# querySelector() behavior with input file type

Tags: javascript, html

so i have an `<input type="file" id="image">`. I use querySelector to get it, let's say:

```
const selectImg = document.querySelector("#image");
```

Then i add an input listener to it:

```
image.addEventListener("input", () =>{
let isFileExists = image.files.length;
console.log(isFileExists);
});
```

The first time i select a file, it works fine, the console prints out 1. But then, if i open the input file again, but not select anything and click "Cancel", the console prints out 0, even when the input file already had a file in it.

Can anyone explain it to me?

Comment: If you open the file dialog again and select nothing, the input will be cleared.

Comment: "The input will be clear", so you are saying is if i selected a file, and then open the input again, choose nothing, the previous selected file will be cleared too?

Comment: @jpesa yes this is the behavior described in w3c standard if you want to keep it use array ,Set or whatever

Comment: @TachibanaShin W3C as nothing to say on this, this is purely HTML and thus specced by WHATWG, and then no, they specifically have a note saying that this exact behavior is not specified and that they can do whatever they want, and actually I think it's not interoperable, at an OS level.

Comment: @kaido I don't really remember who it was specified by because I read it a long time ago. anyway if we want to try to reproduce the behavior OP wants we will need javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#show-the-picker,-if-applicable) have this to say on the matter:

> If *element*'s `type` attribute is in the [File Upload](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#file-upload-state-(type=file)) state, then run these steps [in parallel](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/infrastructure.html#in-parallel):
>
> - Optionally, wait until any prior execution of this algorithm has terminated.
> - Display a prompt to the user requesting that the user specify some files. If the `multiple` attribute is not set on element, there must be no more than one file selected; otherwise, any number may be selected. Files can be from the filesystem or created on the fly, e.g., a picture taken from a camera connected to the user's device.
> - Wait for the user to have made their selection.
> - If the user dismissed the prompt without changing their selection, then [queue an element task](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#queue-an-element-task) on the [user interaction task source](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#user-interaction-task-source) given element to [fire an event](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-event-fire) named `cancel` at *element*, with the `bubbles attribute initialized to true.
> - Otherwise, [update the file selection](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#update-the-file-selection) for element.
>
> > [Note]
> > *As with all user interface specifications, user agents have a good deal of freedom in how they interpret these requirements. The above text implies that a user either dismisses the prompt or changes their selection; exactly one of these will be true. But the mapping of these possibilities to specific user interface elements is not mandated by the standard. For example, a user agent might interpret clicking the "Cancel" button when files were previously selected as a change of selection to select zero files, thus firing `input` and `change`. Or it might interpret such a click as a dismissal that leaves the selection unchanged, thus firing `cancel`. Similarly, it's up to the user agent whether re-selecting the same files counts as were previously selected counts as a dismissal, or as a change of selection*.

(Note that [update the file selection](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#update-the-file-selection) is where both `input` and `change` events are fired).

So it seems that on your system, the input is cleared when you click "Cancel" in the prompt, as is allowed per the note. However beware that not all users will have this behavior, for instance on my macOS system I get

| Action | Chrome | Safari | Firefox |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Click "Cancel" when file selected | Clears the selection | Fire `cancel` event | Fire `cancel` event |
| Select same file | Fire `cancel` event | Fire `input` + `change` event | Fire `cancel` event |
| Click "Cancel" when no file selected | Fire `cancel` event | Fire `cancel` event | Fire `cancel` event |

As you can see, it's a mess, but by listening at the `cancel` event, you can yourself clear the input (`input.value = null`) and get a relatively standard behavior.

But if the input selection is not cleared visually, and the `input` event fires, that would be a browser bug and you may want to report it to your browser's vendor.

Answer (score -1):

You can use 'change' event:

```js
image.addEventListener("change", () =>{
  let isFileExists = image.files.length;
  console.log(isFileExists);
});
```